# Subscribe to event that is raised in Func<>

Tags: c#, events, func

I have a semi generic class that receives a `Func<>` from another class to tell it how to convert data. In a somewhat stripped down fashion, the code it looks like:

```
public class A
{
    public B b;

    public void init()
    {
        b = new B(ConvertRawData);
    }

    public double ConvertRawData(double rawData)
    {
        if(rawData == 1023)
            RaiseMalfunctionEvent();
        return rawData;
    }

    public void CalculateData(double rawData)
    {
        b.CalculateData(rawData);
    }
}

public class B
{
    event EventHandler Malfunction;

    Func<double, double> _converter;
    public B(Func<double, double> converter)
    {
        _converter = converter;
    }

    public void CalculateData(rawData)
    {
        var myVal = _converter(rawData);
    }
}
```

What I am wanting to do is be able to raise an event in the `Func<>` but be able to handle that event in class B.  Right now the event is actually raised in class A.

So my question is how can I make class B without exposing a public event handler in class B? Or is this even possible?

**Edit**
As far as it being an event instead of an exception.  This is external data from a sensor. The sensor sends 1023 to indicate it is in an error state, so I need to flag the data and notify the user, but would it really be an exception in my program?

Comment: C# has the hard requirement that an event is raised in the same class that declares it.  You could add the RaiseMalfunctionEvent() method to class B.

Comment: @HansPassant: That should be an answer.

Comment: Not so sure, looks to me that this should be an exception instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with others, this looks like the best approach is to use exceptions: Create a new exception class `ComnversionMalfunctionException`, throw it in your delegate and then catch it in `CalculateData()`. In the catch clause, you can then raise the event.

But if you don't want to use exceptions, you can do this by passing a delegate to the `converter` delegate that raises the event:

```
public class A
{
    public double ConvertRawData(Action raiseMalfunctionEvent, double rawData)
    {
        if(rawData == 1023)
            raiseMalfunctionEvent();
        return rawData;
    }
}

public class B
{
    event EventHandler Malfunction;

    Func<Action, double, double> _converter;
    public B(Func<Action, double, double> converter)
    {
        _converter = converter;
    }

    public void CalculateData(rawData)
    {
        var myVal = _converter(() => Malfunction(this, EventArgs.Empty), rawData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change it to throw an exception. In class B, I wrapped var myVal = _converter(rawData); in a try/catch block and raised the event there. The event is then raise in class B.  As a side note, this also took care of a couple of side effects I was receiving by not throwing the exception.  Thanks everyone for pointing me straight.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is catch a possible error, you can throw an exception instead of calling `RaiseMalfunctionEvent`, and catch that exception when the function is called.

Comment: It's not really an error in my program though.  This is external data from a sensor.  The value of 1023 indicates the sensor has an error, so I need to flag the result as bad and notify the user, but I'm not sure it would qualify as an exception.

Comment: you dont have to escalate this exception just process it in appropriate way

Answer (score 0):

You can add public method to B that call your event, and pass instance of B into converter. In converter you will be able to call this method.

The second way you can modify CalculateData method to catch special exception and notify about it. inside converter just throw it.

Comment: But this way you can call the method from outside of the delegate.